# PHP json object index

Tags: php, json, object

I have a json, and I do a foreach on this json, i have something like this :

```
object(stdClass) [118]
  public 'value1' => string 'test'
  public 'value2' => string 'test2'
  public 'value3' => string 'test2'
  public 'value4' => string 'test4'
```

I succeed to take value1 and "value2" etc of all my object, but i want to take too the id of these objects. I want to mean, i want to have the "118" for this example. How can i do it ?

Someone to help me ?

Comment: foreach is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over an array you can get both the value of the current item as well as its key by using `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`.

```
foreach ($objects as $index => $object) {
    print_r($index.' '.$object->value1)
}
```

Comment: Objects are not arrays. Does `foreach` work on objects?

Comment: First and foremost, yes `foreach` works on objects by iterating over their public properties (or if they implement special interfaces the iteration does whatever the method implementations do).